# Change HTML Structure of the "jQuery Steps" plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-steps

Since jQuery Steps plugin does not support using your own html markup I need to tweak the plugin to at least support using tags on the 2nd level. The current structure it expects look like this:

```
<div class="wizard">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <section>Content</section>

    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <section>Content</section>
</div>
```

But I need to group steps together using different form tags like this:

```
<div class="wizard">
    <form name="one">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <section>Content</section>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <section>Content</section>
    </form>
    <form name="two">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <section>Content</section>
    </form>
</div>
```

Since Steps uses ".children()" its limited to the immediate child elements. I tried changing children() to find() but that broke it severely. This wizard does everything I need but I need it to support custom markup.

I have already tweaked it to support Twitter Bootstrap but not being able to add additional markup inside the wizard makes everything really challenging.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As we are not the support site for this plugin, you'll have to provide some relevant JavaScript code from it, or else this question will probably be closed as "asking to recommend or find an off-site resource."

Comment: The author of the plugin actually recommended asking questions here for him to answer.

Comment: [He doesn't seem to be answering them anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-steps).